# How to add file extension to pictures send via email

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

The complete script makes a picture with my raspberry pi camera every minute and sends it via email to my adress. The picture is as an attachment in the email but it has no file extension.
1. What do i have to add that the file get the original file extension that they are saved on the raspberry.

Or if its possible:
2. How can I get the pictures embed in the email. This would be much easier so I don`t have to safe them first on my pc.

I hope you all know what I mean, my englich is not the best :)

```
def sendMail(data):
    global texte
    mail = MIMEMultipart()
    mail['Subject'] = "Pictures from home"
    mail['From'] = fromaddr
    mail['To'] = toaddr
    mail.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    dat='%s.jpg'%data
    attachment = open(dat, 'rb')
    image=MIMEImage(attachment.read())
    attachment.close()
    mail.attach(image)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.web.de', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "PASSWORD")
    text = mail.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()


    movepic(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a filename to the attachment, you need to add the `"Content-Disposition"` header to that MIME part, i.e. add this to the code:

```
attachment = open(dat, 'rb')
image=MIMEImage(attachment.read())
attachment.close()
image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=filename.extension')
mail.attach(image)
```

To send the image without saving it to the file, you have to have the image contents and pass them to `MIMEImage` constructor. You are currently reading them from file in `attachment.read()`.

So, if you can pass the image binary (instead of filename) to the function, like this:

```
def sendMail(image_binary_data):
```

then just pass it, like this:

```
image=MIMEImage(image_binary_data)
image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=filename.extension')
mail.attach(image)
```

BTW, if you are reading the image from file, it's safer to open and read files this way, to be sure it always closes properly:

```
with open(dat, 'rb') as image_file:
    image=MIMEImage(image_file.read())
# no need to close explicitly
```

Comment: image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=filename.jpg')
works perfectly, thanks. Now I get the picture send as a .jpg

Comment: @rattionline Cool. You may also _accept_ the answer to show that it solves the problem.